# jquery not able to change input type value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to put onload default data on below field using jquery. But its value is not getting set on this field. I am using daterangepicker.js also. tried using .text() alsno but it is also not workning

```
<div class="large-4 columns crawl_date_outer_box">
            <span>CRAWL DATE</span> <input type="text" id="dateRange"
                class="date" placeholder="Choose a range"
                onClick="dateFilterSelected()">
        </div>
```

my jquery code :

```
function onloadDate(){
    var d1 = new Date();
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate()-30);

    var date1=dateFormat(d1,"MM/dd/yyyy");
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate()-30);

    var date2=dateFormat(d,"MM/dd/yyyy");
    var dateselected1=date1+"-"+date2;
    var presetFromDate = getPresetFilters("fromDate");
    var presetToDate = getPresetFilters("toDate");
    var presetDateOption = getPresetFilters("dateOption");
    console.log(d1,d,date1,date2);
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("onloadDate") == null || sessionStorage.getItem("onloadDate") == undefined || sessionStorage.getItem("onloadDate") == "")
    {
        dateOption = "DateRange";
        $('#dateRange').val(dateselected1);
        sessionStorage.setItem("onloadDate","true");
        console.log("gluing"  + dateselected1);
        applyFiltersOnLoad();

        console.log("filter data with date"+sessionStorage.getItem("filterData"));
    }
    else{
        $('#dateRange').val(dateselected1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is `onloadDate()` being called from?

Comment: Reduce the code to something that is relevant. There are to much function called in this code which we can't see.

Comment: this is called on load @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

please check your function name i think it will be dateFilterSelected()

```
function dateFilterSelected(){
        //some code

    }
```

Comment: How does this answer relate to the problem described in the question?